# How to Alter Photographed Document to Look "Scanned"

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, image-scanner

How can I [do this](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/03/17/jotnot-turns-your-iphones-camera-into-a-document-scanner/) in Python/PIL? I.e., given the four points of an offset rectangle (a photographed document), make it look flat on as if it were scanned.  Is there a simple algorithm for it?

Also, are there any other manipulations I should do to make it look more "scan-like"?

I want to make a simple version of this program for myself in Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at transform() with method set to QUAD

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transform

> ```
> im.transform(size, QUAD, data) => image
> im.transform(size, QUAD, data, filter) => image
> ```
>
> Maps a quadrilateral (a region defined by four corners) from the image to a rectangle with the given size.
>
> Data is an 8-tuple (x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, y3, y3) which contain the upper left, lower left, lower right, and upper right corner of the source quadrilateral.